# Regex lookbehind position of words

Tags: php, regex

The thing was not very nice.

**My regex so far:**

```
(?<!not\s)(?<!n't\s)(nice|friendly|excelent|comfortable|easy access|good|clean|beautiful)
```

I want to match only words (nice,friendly... in this sentence...) if the sentence does not contain words: "not" or "n't" (a.k.a wasn't, isn't). A.k.a positive sentences.

But this regex works only for sentences like:

```
The thing was very not nice.
```

How to write lookbehind to check if the words "not" or "n't" are not in whatever position before my adjectives?

Comment: I think that in regexes, negative lookbehinds can only be of a well defined length (no `+`or `*`), so you would have to list all the possible `n’t` words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a negative look ahead to check there isn't any `not` or `n't` anywhere in the string, and `\K` to throw out the part you don't want:

```
^(?!.*(?:not|n't)).*\K(nice|friendly|excellent|comfortable|easy access|good|clean|beautiful)
```

`(?!...)` will fail if what's inside it matches, `(?:not|n't)` is a non capturing group.

Kind in mind that this is a pretty simple check though. It wouldn't match `nice` in `This is nice but not pretty`. If you want to add more in depth syntax understanding, you'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: Thanks Robin. This seems to be working! Excelent after 2 hours of struggling :) Thx

Comment: @Trki: Glad to help. For the record ("impossible to find bug"?) I added an `l` to the `excellent` in your alternation :)

Comment: Ok :) Sentence: "But this isn't nice." Is selecting "nice". It shouln't. Fixed by: ^(?!.*(?:not|n't)).*\K(nice|friendly|excellent|comfortable|easy access|good|clean|beautiful)

Comment: @Robin why is this happening? https://eval.in/152500 how to fix it please? There should be only one "nice".

Comment: See the [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), you're using a caturing group and the second item in the result array is its value: one item for the match, one for the captured value. Use a non capturing group: `^(?!.*(?:not)).*\\K(?:nice|good|clean)`

Answer (score 0):

Lookbehinds must be fixed-length.

It would perhaps be easier to divide the task. First check if the sentence contains "nice", "friendly" etc., and then in a separate conditional, check if it doesn't contain a negation.

This would make it easier to detect double-negatives too :p

Comment: Yea Niet. I had this idea too but I was so curious i though about it for like 2 hours...